# Writing a regexp that excludes a pattern while matching very generally

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been struggling with this for a bit now. Trying to write a regexp that catches all places where there's a **space before a colon** (`:`)except for certain cases. I want to *not* catch the cases that match something like `?.* :`. As in, a question mark that has a space before it, some sequence of characters, then a space and a colon should be considered okay.

I've tried a bunch of negative lookahead methods etc, but the problem I'm running into is that the main pattern is *more general* than the exclusion pattern, so it's not able to exclude what I want.

`\s+:` catches all the bad cases, but also catches two false positives. `(\s+\?.*\s+:)` catches only the false positives. How do I combine them so that I don't get the false positives?

---

Bad cases (should be caught):

```
var type : CGFloat = 5.0
let dictionary = [
    "string" : "key"
]
let dictionary = [Container<Thing?>(value: value) : "woohoo"]
```

Good cases (shouldn't be caught):

```
var aTest = true ? "true" : "false"
let dict = [
    "string": "key"
]
class ATest: SuperType
let multiLineTernary = true
    ? "a String"
    : "b String"
```

Comment: Can you make it a little bit clearer?

Comment: your examples are not clear... please provide string, and (expected output or  srings for true, false positive and negatives)